# How to force end gateways to regenerate in minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

On my server, we just pruned the end because we have a world border and ran out of cities. Everything seems to be working great now, except for one thing: End gates are spawning above the void. This is impossible when looking at the game code, so our guess is that the gate locations are saved somewhere in NBT data. Naturally, I went looking around, but I didn't find anything, so I was hoping someone here could help.

In short: Is there a way to force end gateways to regenerate correctly (and possibly delete the old ones)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured out the solution to the problem. First it is important to note that the teleportation data is stored in block data. Secondly, when in the end, an end portal without block data defaults to its spawning state.

The way to fix the problem is to respawn all end gateway blocks via the set block command. Example for gateway 17:
`/setblock 29 75 -91  minecraft:end_gateway 0`

This will respawn that particular gateway and everything will run smoothly from there.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there's no command to forcibly spawn the end gates, and I don't think there's one to spawn the portal inside of them either.

My solution is to delete the region file in the saves and regenerate the chunk itself, it shouldn't be spawning above void.

Also, is this vanilla and are there some plugins that could effect the spawning?

Comment: There is a command to forcible spawn the end gate block, it's along the lines of: `/setblock ~ ~2 ~ minecraft:end_gateway 0 replace {Age:180,ExactTeleport:1,ExitPortal:{X:1,Y:2,Z:3}}`
Deleting the region files doesn't help, because the exit is stored in block data. So we're now at the point where we're running experiments to see what happens if we force a block spawn without block data.